# Pdf generated with jasper-reports - DejaVu font not showing correctly, but only if application deployed on local websphere

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm developing reports with jasper.
I'm using DejaVu default font to limit problems.
Anyway I front this issue.
In local environment, Windows, I develop templates in a test project using Tomcat WebServer. I use this project only to develop jrxml. The reports are generated with the right font.
Then I import my .jasper templates in the real project, deployed on Websphere 8.5, also in local environment, Windows, but when I ran the web application and generate the templates, they miss the font.

In test or production environment, Linux, WebSphere 8.5 all seems ok with the font correctly shown.
I did not do anything special on test and production servers.

I can validate the final report with local Tomcat, but I'm corius to understand why local Websphere does not show the font.
What I can check?

Comment: Are you using font extensions?

Comment: to tell the truth I was no very aware about it. I took a look here https://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/tibco-jaspersoft-studio-user-guide/v640/working-font-extensions to understand, now I can say no, I'm not working with font extensions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me...
After some days in which I put aside this problem, today while I was setting up an already implented web application in which I have to do some coding on the same local Websphere, when I was setting the ***shared libraries***, I got that I was missing ***jasperreports-fonts-6.9.0.jar***.
In Tomcat folders instead the jar was present.